# Elasticsearch - Aggregation and Bucket size

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I have data in ES which looks like this:

```
'{"Emp_ID":"12212","Emp_Name":"Jim","Emp_Sal":300,"Dep_Id":22,"Dep_Name":"IT","Dep_Cnt":40}'     
'{"Emp_ID":"6874590","Emp_Name":"Joe","Emp_Sal":140,"Dep_Id":66,"Dep_Name":"Admin","Dep_Cnt":20}'
'{"Emp_ID":"32135","Emp_Name":"Jill","Emp_Sal":170,"Dep_Id":66,"Dep_Name":"Admin","Dep_Cnt":20}' 
'{"Emp_ID":"43312","Emp_Name":"Andy","Emp_Sal":450,"Dep_Id":22,"Dep_Name":"IT","Dep_Cnt":40}'    
'{"Emp_ID":"315609","Emp_Name":"Cody","Emp_Sal":150,"Dep_Id":22,"Dep_Name":"IT","Dep_Cnt":40}'   
'{"Emp_ID":"87346","Emp_Name":"Dave","Emp_Sal":500,"Dep_Id":55,"Dep_Name":"hr","Dep_Cnt":10}'
```

I want to get all the unique departments ordered by Dep_Cnt, for which I wrote the following query

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "by_Dep_Cnt":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"Dep_Cnt",
            "order":{  
               "_term":"asc"
            }
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "by_unique_dep_id":{  
               "terms":{  
                  "field":"Dep_Id"
               },
               "aggs":{  
                  "tops":{  
                     "top_hits":{  
                        "size":1
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And got expected output of 3 unique departments ordered by Dep_Cnt.
But now my requirement is to get only the top two departments.
How do I modify the query to get only 2 buckets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the parameter `size` of the `terms` aggregation:

***If*** `Dep_Cnt` is the number of employees in your department and your document are per employee and you have all the employee in your index (from your mapping it may be the case) you can just do:

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "by_Dep_Id":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"Dep_Id",
            "size": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Since by default it will sort by the number of documents with the corresponding value i.e. the number of documents with this Dep_Id i.e. the number of employees in this department.

***If you are not in this situation:***

Your current request does not behave the same way when you have two department with the same size (you will have two `Dep_Id`s in the same bucket of `Dep_Cnt`)

You can group documents by `Dep_Id`, get the `Dep_Cnt` using the metric you want (min, max, avg, ...) and sort on this metric:

```
{  
   "size":0,
   "aggs":{  
      "by_Dep_Id":{  
         "terms":{  
            "field":"Dep_Id",
            "size": 2
            "order":{  
               "avg_Dep_Cnt":"asc"
            }
         },
         "aggs":{  
            "avg_Dep_Cnt":{  
               "avg":{  
                  "field":"Dep_Cnt"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

NB: I removed the top_hits aggregations since you do not need them according to what you explained, if you have extra requirement just add them in the aggregation.